# Assigning int array to a int pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I want to assign value of an array to a pointer or need a better way to do the below operation .

I have a structure

```
struct ver{
    int *a;
    int *b
    int *c;
}

struct Versions{
    int ver1[3];
    int ver2[3];
    int ver3[9];
}

static const Versions versionsinfo[] {
    "001234",
    {0,18,0},
    "000000"
};

static Temp_Data;

Versions * GetVersions() {
    Versions * pt = NULL;
    memcpy(&Temp_Data,&versionsinfo[1]);
    pt = &Temp_Data;
    return pt ;
}

struct Versions *pointer;
pointer = GetVersions();    

struct ver *newVer;
newVer->a= pointer->ver1;
newVer->b= pointer->ver2;
newVer->c= pointer->ver3;
```

I want to assign the value of Ver1 to a member of struct ver , either a, b or c.

can anyone please let me know if this is possible in C.

Comment: You mean like `newVer->a=Ver1`?

Comment: why segmentation fault?

Comment: what is the code that you have?  This is simple c.

Comment: Its just `newVer->a = Ver1; newVer->b = Ver2; newVer->c = Ver3;`. What is the issue ?

Comment: You need to allocate some memory for `struct ver *newVer;` before you can copy to its members.

Comment: "... want to assign the value of Ver1 ..." --> Arrays can not be _assigned_.  Code like `newVer->a=Ver1` will assign the address of `Ver1[0]` to the pointer  `newVer->a`.   pranathi, Describe your overall goal in more detail.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? This smells somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I get segmentation fault if I do this and my device keeps resetting .

Comment: I have updated the question . So if I execute this code on the device , my device is resetting continuously

Comment: What is `newVer` pointing to?

Comment: pranathi, Hint, what is the value of `newVer` in the line `newVer->a= Ver1;`?  The prior line `struct ver *newVer;` does not initialize `newVer` to anything.

Comment: What is `GetVersions`?

Comment: Perhaps you could change the type of `newVer` to `struct ver` (instead of `struct ver *`) unless you specifically need `newVer` to be a pointer. Then set the members using `newVer.a = pointer->ver1;`, `newVer.b = pointer->ver2;`, `newVer.c = pointer->ver3;`.

Comment: Your code looks very wrong. Lots of `;` missing, wrong syntax, etc. Please post a [MCVE]. It's so wrong that it's really hard to guess what your intention is.

Comment: Thanks @lan Abbott!. That solved my reset problem , but still I cannot get the correct values assigned from `newVer.b = pointer->ver2`

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
int Ver1[3];
int Ver2[9];
int Ver3[9];
```

They are initializing arrays of type int. So if you want to get those numbers (which are the sizes of the arrays in the above) you need to do

```
int Ver1 = 3;
int Ver2 = 9;
int Ver3 = 9;
```

The allocate some memory for the pointer

```
struct ver *newVer = malloc(sizeof(newVer));
```

and then put the values in the struct

```
newVer[0].a = Ver1;
newVer[0].b = Ver2;
newVer[0].c = Ver3;
```

Comment: `sizeof(newVer)` --> `sizeof *newVer`.  `malloc(sizeof(newVer))` allocates the size of the pointer, not the structure.

Comment: Or `newVer[0].a = &Ver1` if your compiler won't convert.

Comment: Thanks for the response tadman!! but I just want to assign member of struct Versions. Could you please take a look at my updated question .

Comment: @PerfectContrast Do you mean `newVer[0].a = &Ver1;` and so on ?

Comment: @Prajval Nope . I want the whole content in  `ver1[3]  in int*a`

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(newVer));` remains incorrect code as the allocation is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
struct ver
{
  int *a;
  int *b;
  int *c;
};

int Ver1[3] = {1,2,3};
int Ver2[3] = {1,2,3};;
int Ver3[9];

struct ver *newVer;

int main()
{
   struct ver newV;/*the memory for struct var is allocated in main */

   newVer = (struct ver *)malloc(sizeof(struct ver));/*memory allocated in heap*/

   newV.a = Ver1;/*OR newVar.a = &Ver1[0];*/
   newV.b = Ver2;
   newV.c = Ver3;
   printf("newV->a[0] is %d", newV.a[0]);
  /*OR*/
  newVer->a = Ver1;
  newVer->b = Ver2;
  newVer->c = Ver3;
  printf("\nnewVar->a[1] is %d", newVer->a[1]);
  free(newVer); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious, why do you code `(struct ver *)`?  Why not drop it?

Comment: malloc returns (void*) which works just fine, but it's good practice to specify (struct ver *)

Comment: The cast if s OK, but about 80% suggest not to cast: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2410359).  Consider `newVer = malloc(sizeof *newVer);`  It is easy to code right, review and maintain.